# spring data mongodb geointersection

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, spring-data

I have a need to find a union of two distance criteria.
For example, I have suppliers located at `Point A` (long, lat) that ship within a radius of `200km`

I have buyers located at `Point B` (long,lat)- they are looking to purchase within a radius of `300km`.

How can I write a mongodb query that can find the appropriate (matching buyers and sellers) - an intersection of their respective business areas.

Can I store each `area` of concern as a polygon?

I am stuck here. I have used geoNear and it does not include a union- it is just one way match

Comment: The challenge is to represent these areas of interest as poloygons centered at each respective Point with a radius.  Once can represent a circle as a GeoJson polygon and then invoke the mongodb $geointersects operator to see if the geometries intersect

Comment: Also, does spring data support the $geointersect operator?  I found these links  https://github.com/lcanet/spring-data-mongo-spatial

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/128265-mongo-2-4-2dsphere-support. Spring data mongodb seems to not be really supported.  Almost all of my questions regarding it are never answered.